# Is it possible to use Session::get() method in database.php file?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.6

I am Abdullah. I want to use multiple database connection in laravel 5.6. But i want change the database dynamically. best way for me the using Session::get() method in config/database.php.

'connections' => [

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'default_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'mysql2' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => 'changeable_db',
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],

],
```

I want to change the changeable database by using Session::get('db') method. is it possible or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible because when you change any configuration in your config file and use `php artisan` to serve you application. You have to stop the running serve and restart It for laravel to take in consideration new configuration. Laravel doesn't hot reload configuration.

My advice is to define many `connection` inside the `database.php` file as you need and when you whan to switch to another connection you can specify it by providing the name of the given connection like this

```
$users = DB::connection('connection_name')
    ->table('users')
    ->where('name', 'John')->first();
```

You can switch connection has you need inside Controller or somewhere else

If you want to change connection on specific Model you can perform it this way

```
$user = new user();
$user->setConnection('connection_name');
```

Comment: Thant's i know. when i want to create one db for each user if have large number of user then my db number also be large so that i want change connection dynamically. that's why i want to use session or any other way to connection name dynamically by session or any other's way